# alpine.js - populating form data with button

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I am trying to use alpine.js to update a form's action, and am running into some confusion.

My code:

```
<div x-data="data=''">
    <template x-if="data.url">
        <div>
            <form method=POST :action="data.url">
                <input type="text" x-model="data.sitenumber">
                <button type="submit">Submit form</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </template>
    <input type="button" value="add data" @click="data = {url: 'www.com', sitenumber: 23}">
</div>
```

When I click on the button, the div form doesn't appear. My ultimate goal is to have a modal popup that is dynamically updated with an action button (delete record, etc.) when a link/button elsewhere in the document is clicked.

I tried following long with this [ToDo app tutorial](https://mejlak.com/blog/alpinejs-not-another-javascript-framework/), but this creates a separate function, and I thought it would be possible to pass simple data variables to a different part of the div, especially since I'm not looping through an array.

Thanks!

Comment: the form is never visible, because data.url is initially always empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you do `x-data="data=''"` instead of using object initialisation syntax: `x-data="{ data: '' }"`

Comment: Hi, thank you! That was it exactly, I was initializing the object incorrectly. I popped that in, and the data passed in from the button click to my form. I appreciate the help :)